# Stop execution of main function after error is thrown inside callback function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, error-handling, callback, throw

I have an async function (main) being called from another function (A).
I am doing a Redis transaction in main function, if a certain criteria is met then I want to throw an error and stop further execution of the main process.

So far, by using a callback function, I am able to log the error message but the execution of main process continues (I haven't used throw err, just consoloe.log in callback).

How do I stop them from executing once callback function is called? I had tried with return but since it's inside of couple of callback, that doesn't work.

```
const main = async (callback) => {
try {
    redisClient.watch("someKey",  function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        redisClient.get("someKey", function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            if (result == null) {
                redisClient.multi().set("someKey", "true").exec(function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        throw err;
                    }
                    console.log(result);
                });
            } else {
                redisClient.multi().discard();
                
                return callback(new Error("error msg"));
            }
        });
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    throw err;
}

.....
```

This is body of function A -

```
try {
await main(function (response) {
  console.log(response.message);
});

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    await deleteKey("someKey");
  }
```

Comment: It is called "Callback Hell"

Comment: Any way around this?